# How do you ignore the palm of the hand when doing multitouch drawing?

Tags: iphone, multi-touch

Several multitouch drawing applications have implemented features that prevent interference when a user rests their palm on the screen while drawing.

How do they filter out touch events from the palm of the hand, but allow the correct input from the drawing finger or stylus?

Comment: Hi Brad, u have find the solution for above problem

Answer (score 5):

Ignore any multi-touch inputs that are close to each other, only taking the data from the single point (the finger).

Comment: Thanks for help. but can you provide pseudo code for that how to handle that ?

Comment: Hello @Greg, can you provide some code snippet, how this can be done

Answer (score 1):

Take the top y component from the group of touches.