# Multitouch tracking issue

Tags: ios, uikit, core-graphics, multi-touch, uibezierpath

I am working with multitouch while writing, So basically what I am doing is, I am writing with hand support, because typically, its how user rights, I followed this link [How to ignore certain UITouch Points in multitouch sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20853765/how-to-ignore-certain-uitouch-points-in-multitouch-sequence)

So, what I am doing is , I am tracking a touch Object in touchesBegan and using that only in touchesMoved.Everything works fine, but some times while writing, I get this line

[image]

In the above image, you can see the thick line which suddenly comes while writing with my hand touched on the screen

Here is the code

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSLog(@"Touches began");   

    UITouch* topmostTouch = self.trackingTouch;
    for (UITouch *touch in touches)
    {
        bufIdx = 0;
        isFirstTouchPoint = YES;
        ctr = 0;

        pts[0] = [touch locationInView:self];


        if(!topmostTouch || [topmostTouch locationInView:self].y > pts[0].y)
        {
            topmostTouch = touch;
            //touchStartPoint1 = pts[0];
        }
        else
        {
            pts[0] = pts[3];
        }
    }

   if (self.trackingTouch != nil && self.trackingTouch != topmostTouch) 
   {
     [self discardDrawing];        
   }

    self.trackingTouch = topmostTouch;
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{    
        // Find the touch that we track for drawing

            CGPoint p = [self.trackingTouch locationInView:self];
            ctr++;
            pts[ctr] = p;

            if (ctr == 4)
            {
                pts[3] = midPoint(pts[2], pts[4]);

                for ( int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                {
                    pointsBuffer[bufIdx + i] = pts[i];
                }

                bufIdx += 4;

                dispatch_async(drawingQueue, ^{
                    //UIBezierPath *offsetPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPath]; // ................. (2)

                    self.currentPath = [[DrawingPath alloc] init];                   
                    [self.currentPath setPathColor:self.lineColor];


                    if (bufIdx == 0) return;

                    LineSegment ls[4];
                    for ( int i = 0; i < bufIdx; i += 4)
                    {
                        if (isFirstTouchPoint) // ................. (3)
                        {                           
                            ls[0] = (LineSegment){pointsBuffer[0], pointsBuffer[0]};
                            [self.currentPath.path moveToPoint:ls[0].firstPoint];                      
                            isFirstTouchPoint = NO;                   
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ls[0] = lastSegmentOfPrev;

                        }


                        float frac1 = self.lineWidth/clamp(len_sq(pointsBuffer[i], pointsBuffer[i+1]), LOWER, UPPER); // ................. (4)
                        float frac2 = self.lineWidth/clamp(len_sq(pointsBuffer[i+1], pointsBuffer[i+2]), LOWER, UPPER);
                        float frac3 = self.lineWidth/clamp(len_sq(pointsBuffer[i+2], pointsBuffer[i+3]), LOWER, UPPER);



                        ls[1] = [self lineSegmentPerpendicularTo:(LineSegment){pointsBuffer[i], pointsBuffer[i+1]} ofRelativeLength:frac1]; // ................. (5)
                        ls[2] = [self lineSegmentPerpendicularTo:(LineSegment){pointsBuffer[i+1], pointsBuffer[i+2]} ofRelativeLength:frac2];
                        ls[3] = [self lineSegmentPerpendicularTo:(LineSegment){pointsBuffer[i+2], pointsBuffer[i+3]} ofRelativeLength:frac3];



                        [self.currentPath.path  moveToPoint:ls[0].firstPoint]; // ................. (6)
                        [self.currentPath.path  addCurveToPoint:ls[3].firstPoint controlPoint1:ls[1].firstPoint controlPoint2:ls[2].firstPoint];
                        [self.currentPath.path  addLineToPoint:ls[3].secondPoint];
                        [self.currentPath.path  addCurveToPoint:ls[0].secondPoint controlPoint1:ls[2].secondPoint controlPoint2:ls[1].secondPoint];
                        [self.currentPath.path  closePath];

                        lastSegmentOfPrev = ls[3]; // ................. (7)
                    }


                     dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                            bufIdx = 0;

                            [m_pathArray addObject:self.currentPath];
                            [self setNeedsDisplay];

                        });
                    });


                pts[0] = pts[3];
                pts[1] = pts[4]; 
                ctr = 1;
            }
        }        
}
```

So friends, please help me out.

Comment: Approach mentioned in this post might work for you [Stackoverflow link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20853765/how-to-ignore-certain-uitouch-points-in-multitouch-sequence

Comment: @bhavyakothari, I think you have not read my question properly, I have followed the same link and also I have mentioned it in my question

Answer (score 4):

You will need to debug to confirm, but it appears to be related to your logic in `touchesBegan:withEvent:`. In this method, you check each time there is a new touch to determine if it is the 'highest', but when the highest touch does actually change you don't seem to abort / reset any existing drawing.

Your best approach is probably using logging to determine if / when the 'highest' touch is changing and what affect that has on the in-progress line.

Also, in `touchesMoved:`, you don't need the `for (UITouch *touch in touches)` loop as you already have a reference to `self.trackingTouch` so you can just use it directly.

Comment: Hello @Wain, thanks for your reply, I have made edits to the code according to your suggestion, I meant I am showing the code, how I abort any existing drawing. One thing I have noticed, while testing is that, it happens only when while writing , if your two or more hand fingers touches the screen below, if only one finger apart from the drawing finger is touching, then it writes correctly.

Comment: From looking at the code I *guess* by destroying `self.currentPath` and resetting `ctr` to zero to restart your line drawing algorithm.

Comment: When I should do this? In touchesBegan when I get the higher value touch? But I am always creating a new self.currentPath or very touchesMoved. What say? @Wain

Comment: Where you have added the call to `discardDrawing`. That should just cancel the current line and start a new one. I don't know your drawing algorithm or have time to study it so you need to decide how to cancel the current line when you detect a bad touch...

Comment: Hello @Wain, if you check my above code, I have added the call to dicardDrawing in touchesBegan. Are you not able to view it?

Comment: I can see you added a call to it, I don't know what that results in though. You really need to debug to verify what is happening.

Comment: ok @Wain, I will explain you, I have two layers, one is temporary and one is permanent, so while drawing, I draw into temporary and on touches ended , I draw it into permanent. So now in discard drawing, I am just clearing out the temporary layer.

Comment: Anyways, I will debug, and get back to you. Thanks

Comment: Hello @Wain, please look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21935064/undo-with-multitouch-drawing-in-ios

Comment: Hello @Wain what you have to say ?

Comment: Hello @Wain, I am facing on serious issue, if I write with multitouch, I am drawing is not smooth, but if I write with single touch, it is smooth, can you throw some light on it, Here is my SO question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21935064/undo-with-multitouch-drawing-in-ios

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your problem correctly, you're having undesired strokes whenever the user uses multiple fingers on your canvas. Since you already have a `self.trackingTouch`, will it be reasonable to just ignore every other touch that is not `self.trackingTouch`?

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if (self.trackingTouch)
    {
        // another touch is active so we ignore this one
        return;
    }
    // ...the rest of your code
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = self.trackingTouch;
    if (![touches containsObject:touch])
    {
        // updates to touches other than self.trackingTouch
        return;
    }

    // ...process only self.trackingTouch in the rest of your code
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = self.trackingTouch;
    if (![touches containsObject:touch])
    {
        // updates to touches other than self.trackingTouch
        return;
    }

    // ...process only self.trackingTouch in the rest of your code

   self.trackingTouch = nil;
}

-(void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    // ...same as touchesEnded:withEvent:
}
```

Comment: Hey @John thanks for your reply, I am ignoring all other touches becuase, in touchesBegan, I am checking a condition and based on that I am deciding the tracking touch. So whats wrong in that?

Comment: @Ranjit Have you made updates to your code since you posted this question? It might be helpful to update the original post.

Comment: @John, I have not made major changes that would change my original post.

Comment: Hello @John, on touches ended why are you making self.trackingTouch = nil; and in touchesBegan you say, if(self.trackingTouch) then return. Can you explain this to me

Comment: Hello @John, please look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21935064/undo-with-multitouch-drawing-in-ios

Comment: Hello @John Estropia, my curves are getting jagged when I write with hand support, what you have to say, what might be going wrong, here is the SO question for your reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21952274/how-to-effectively-manage-multitouch-in-ios

Comment: Hello @John, I need your help, please help me out